# want to get the previous URL in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using spring security for user authentication, But here i want to get the previous browser url on userDetailService or loginFailure or loginSuccess.

For that i am trying to get the url from the request object but i got **/j_Spring_security_check** instead of browser url like:- **/service/user/login or /service/customer/login** because i have these two different url for login for different user or customer. please suggest any solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: are you talking about default -target URL or Referer ?

Comment: i am looking for Referer....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Note: the [HTTP referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_REFERER) is a client-controlled value and can thus be spoofed to something entirely different or even removed. This value should not be used for any critical operation. But why you needs this?